# NSMutableArray with NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Here is the situation:
I have a request on `AFNetworking` that retrieves me a `JSON` with an `NSArray`.

My goal is to mutate the `NSDictionaries` inside it. I already made a `mutableCopy` of the array, but I want to know if I can easily mutate all the content. Will I have to iterate through the array manually?

Comment: Even mutating the array to mutable array I still cant change the dictionary content because it is not a mutable dictionary. I want to know if there is a way to make the all mutable in a smart way

Comment: In general, if you can't get the dictionaries/arrays in mutable form to begin with, you must iterate through them to make a "deep" mutable copy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSJSONSerialization has options to allow you to control the mutability of the resulting data structure. Just pass the appropriate ones (probably `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`) and there you go.

Comment: Awesome! For some reason I passed through that and didn't noticed that option, that for pointing me that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mutate `NSDictionary`, just because only `NSMutableDictionary` has method `setObject:forKey:`

So you should create `mutableCopy` of each dictionary and empty mutable array. Then with a `for`loop fill that array. Your code should be so:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)mutatedArrayFromArray:(NSArray *)array
{
  NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
  if([array count] > 0)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      NSMutableDictionary *mutatedItem = [[array objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];
      [resultArray addObject:mutatedItem];
      [mutatedItem release]; // only with ARC disabled
    }
  }
  return [result autorelease]; // if ARC enabled : return result;
}
```